# Rails associations - orders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have been trying to create a dummy application to try and learn Rails.  The app I thought I could create is a coffee ordering app for a group of people in work.

- So the website will have many `users`.
- A user can create a `coffee_order`.
- A coffee order contains orders for other individual users.
- Each user can have one or more `coffee_shop_items` (e.g. latte,
  cappuccino,danish, muffin,  etc)
- A coffee order also has an `assignee`, this is the person who is tasked
  with going and getting the order.

So as a `user`, I create a coffee order, select an assignee, add users to the order, and add one or more coffee shop items to each user,

I am really struggling with how the database should be, and what the associations need to be, along with any join tables?

I am also trying to use nested attributes for the form entry.

Thanks in advance for help.

Update with some code I have tried to create a coffee order:

```
        @coffee_order = CoffeeOrder.new(coffee_order_params)

       params[:coffee_order][:user_coffee_orders_attributes].each do |user_order|
         order = @coffee_order.user_coffee_orders.new(user_id: user_order[1][:user_id].to_i)

         user_order[1][:coffee_shop_items].each do |item|
           coffee_shop_item = CoffeeShopItems.find(item) if item != ""
          # this line fails! see error below
           @coffee_order.user_coffee_orders.coffee_shop_items << coffee_shop_item if coffee_shop_item != nil
         end

       end
```

error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `coffee_shop_items' for #<UserCoffeeOrder::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x42c6180>):
```

Answer (score 0):

The coffee_shop_items belong to the order, not the user. After all, a user could probably create another order another day? You should probably also check out the rails documentation, which, IIRC actually contains a walk-through of a shopping cart application.

```
User has_many :coffes_orders
User has_many :coffee_orders_he_needs_to_get, class_name: "CoffeeOrder", foreign_key: "assignee_id"

CoffeeOrder belongs_to :user
CoffeeOrder belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User"
CoffeeOrder has_and_belongs_to_many :coffee_shop_items

Coffee_shop_items has_and_belongs_to_many :coffee_orders
```

Comment: I updated my question with the code I have tried, please let me know if there is anything obvious.